# URL file-access is disabled in the server

Tags: php

I Know this is a problem in the php.ini which comes with a default **allow_url_fopen = Off** and **allow_url_include = Off**
How could i deal with this... if the hosting place dont change this.. im trying to access an outside url totally diferent from mine, so the server root thing wont work.. what could i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a HTTP client PHP class to obtain the data:
http://scripts.incutio.com/httpclient/

You can save it as a local file, execute it or do anything. Just be careful not to include some malicious code by mistake (that's why allow_url_include is off by default).

Comment: That's why **allow_url_include** is off by default. `allow_url_fopen` is [on by default](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/php.ini-production?revision=300715&view=markup#l803).

Comment: Most of the time, cURL is present; in those cases there's no need to use a PHP implementation of the HTTP protocol. cURL is likely less buggy and more secure than a PHP HTTP implementation.